# Navigating to angularJS page from url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

How come I can't navigate to a page using a regular url? For example I have a page at `/about`, but if I open a new tab and try to go to `http://localhost:3000/about` I'll get the general `Cannot GET '/about'` error.

But if I go to `http://localhost:3000/#!/about` it renders the page and changes the url to a clean url without the `#!`.

I have `html5Mode(true)` set.

I'm using version 1.6.6 of angular and angular-route

Comment: did you pass $locationProvider as an argument into your factory? app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)

Comment: also why include the #! with html5mode you don't need to use this you can just access it via url.tld/path

Comment: Yeah I don't use `#!` in the code.From code update the location works fine using `location.path('path')` but if I type that into a url it doesn't work